# Typescript: compilation errors when updating Firebase function dependencies

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I tried to update the dependencies of my Firebase functions project to use more recent versions of firebase-functions and firebase-admin, which in turn seemed to required more recent versions of TypeScript and tslint. Here is my resulting package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.8",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.1.2",
    "html-pdf": "^2.2.0",
    "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
    "json2csv": "^4.1.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.9.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validator": "^10.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

But now with that, when I try to deploy my Firebase functions, I get a bunch of Typescript compilation errors I can't even understand. Anybody has any idea what those are and how to fix them or work around them?

```
Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run build

> functions@ build /Users/sarbogast/dev/myproject/backend/functions
> tsc

node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.d.ts:35:29 - error TS2694: Namespace '"http"' has no exported member 'OutgoingHttpHeaders'.

35     extensionHeaders?: http.OutgoingHttpHeaders;
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:54:11 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.

54 interface IteratorResult<T> {}
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:41:6
    41 type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'IteratorResult' was also declared here.

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:41:6 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.

41 type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:54:11
    54 interface IteratorResult<T> {}
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'IteratorResult' was also declared here.


Found 3 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sarbogast/.npm/_logs/2019-09-03T14_57_53_748Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

Comment: FWIW, having the same issue. Will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/551

Comment: Any news on the issue, I started having it.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to fix this by adding "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"] to compilerOptions in the tsconfig.json.

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/551#issuecomment-561504411)

Answer (score 3):

So here is how I managed to solve the issue: I installed @types/node as an explicit dev dependency and it was enough. Here is what my package.json ended up looking like:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.8",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.2.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.1.2",
    "html-pdf": "^2.2.0",
    "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
    "json2csv": "^4.1.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.9.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validator": "^10.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.7.5",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An error that points to a file that begins with `node_modules` and ends with `.d.ts` is a typescript [lib check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck). These are designed to catch type conflicts between installed modules but can be tricky to set up correctly.

I usually just switch it off, and get the added benefit of a faster compile time.

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        ...
    }
}
```