# Firebase Function deploy throwing typescript errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using typescript with Firebase Functions. When I try to deploy using `npm run deploy` inside functions directory. It throws too many typescript errors.

```
../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3208:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'feFuncB' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGFEFuncBElement>', but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGFEFuncBElement>'.

3208             feFuncB: React.SVGProps<SVGFEFuncBElement>;
                 ~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3108:13
    3108             feFuncB: React.SVGProps<SVGFEFuncBElement>;
                     ~~~~~~~
    'feFuncB' was also declared here.

../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3209:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'feFuncG' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGFEFuncGElement>', but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGFEFuncGElement>'.

3209             feFuncG: React.SVGProps<SVGFEFuncGElement>;
                 ~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3109:13
    3109             feFuncG: React.SVGProps<SVGFEFuncGElement>;
                     ~~~~~~~
    'feFuncG' was also declared here.

../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3210:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'feFuncR' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGFEFuncRElement>', but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGFEFuncRElement>'.

3210             feFuncR: React.SVGProps<SVGFEFuncRElement>;
                 ~~~~~~~

 
../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3222:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'filter' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGFilterElement>', but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGFilterElement>'.

3222             filter: React.SVGProps<SVGFilterElement>;
```

tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Seems like typescript is going through the node modules folder.

Comment: Please don't post text as screenshots. Instead post the actual text (code, error messages, data, etc) and use the tools of Stack Overflow to mark them up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: compilation errors when updating Firebase function dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774441/typescript-compilation-errors-when-updating-firebase-function-dependencies)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{ 
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "outDir": "lib", 
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strict": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]  // <-- here
    },  
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": ["src"]
  }
}
```